# How to get Image's string value(or an Image reference) from a ImageView

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

I have assigned a textview and a ImageView as below,

```
Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
```

Now their values will change dynamically in my program (Image changed from a online url), and at the end I need to store their values in db for future use. here i get text value as

```
String TextValue = Text.getText().toString();
```

but how I store value from ImageView?

```
String ImageValue = Image.someFunctionThatReturnsImageReferenceInString();
```

Is there any such functions??
Or how to do this.. Pls help

Comment: First `Image.getText().toString()` not possible and second more clear `what you want?`

Comment: what is `String ImageValue = Image.getText().toString();` ?? Wrong concept

Comment: IntelliJ AmiyaYeah that wont work... thats what I mentioned.....

Comment: but I need to store the image reference in Db for further reference - MD

Comment: Store the image URI somewhere (variable, SharedPreferences, db, ...) before setting the ImageView image.

Answer (score 5):

you need to convert image-view into base64 string like below.

1]convert imageview to bitmap.

```
  imageView.buildDrawingCache();
  Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

2]bitmap to base64 String.

```
public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
      byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
      // get the base 64 string
      String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
  return imgString;
}
```

3]base64 to bitmap.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(Base64String.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

set this bitmap to imageview.

Comment: well, can I use this string to display the same image again??

Comment: or can u help how do I display the same image again form this String??

Comment: i have updated my answer with convert base64 to bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no getImageResource() or getDrawableId(). Try this one may be it will help full for you.

```
imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
imageView1.setTag(R.drawable.apple);
imageView2.setTag(R.drawable.banana);
```

If you like, you can create a simple function to get the drawable id:

```
private int getDrawableId(ImageView iv) {
    return (Integer) iv.getTag();
}
```

Comment: Please mark as accepted if it is help full for you.

Comment: well actually, The Image value change time to time, and I need to save the image reference at particular time.. So drawable id wont help as It will be same for all the images

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get the imageName of a specific image that was retrieved from URL which may looks like this.
Your Image URL

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/myImage.png
```

Now you can do

```
URI uri = new URI("http://example.com/foo/bar/myImage.png
");
String path = uri.getPath();
String imageName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

And you can do whatever you want with `imageName`

Comment: Actually my Imageview is placed in a RecyclerView and user are allowed to click on each Items. I need to save the clicked Items and display the clicked item in next activity... So I cant store the url as string directly..

Comment: @JosephJoseph can you please make clear why you can't store URL's last path segment as string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Drawable like this

```
Drawable drawable = Image.getDrawable();
```

Or Bitmap like this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)Image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```